# c# LINQ AsEnumerable Groupby Where

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable that I am returning to the UI layer.

I have multiple tables with the same FirstId value. A few may have a value in teh FieldOne. I only want to group the records where FieldOne is null.

I tried the following LINQ statement with .Where and .Groupby but the .Where removes all the records with values in FieldOne and then do the GroupBy. In the UI grid, the records with FieldOne values are missing. I want to only group the records with empty FieldOne values and still have the records with FieldOne values. Thanks.

```
MyDataAsEnumerable()
    .Where(f => f.Field<string>("FieldOne") == null)
    .GroupBy(r => new { pp1 = r.Field<int>("FirstId") })
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Perhaps FieldOne is the empty string and not null?  Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Field<string>("FieldOne")` in your `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an artifical grouping key:

```
.GroupBy(
  r => new { pp1 = f.Field<string>("FieldOne") == null ? -1 : r.Field<int>("FirstId") })
```

Here, I used `-1` as a hack to create a separate group. Make sure this int value is not in use. You could also solve this precisely but hopefully this is OK.